# jQuery .removeClass gets ignored

Tags: jquery

So there's a popup I need to hide on button click. And everything goes right when I fire .removeClass from any other trigger, but once I add .removeClass line in my btn.click function it gets ignored.

```
closePopupBtn.click(function() {
    url = commentInput.val();
    if (url.length > 1) {
        var imgType = commentImgURL.slice(-4),
            availableTypes = ['.jpg', '.png', 'jpeg'];

        if (availableTypes.indexOf(imgType) > -1) {
            $popUp.removeClass('image-add-enabled');
            commentInput.val("");
            $container.append(commentImgHTML);
        };
     } else {
         $container.addClass('error');
     };
});
```

So

> $popUp.removeClass('image-add-enabled');

is the issue here. Code after .removeClass line executes fine.

Here's the code I'm using add class I need to remove in function above

```
showPopupBtn.click(function() {
    $popUp.addClass('image-add-enabled');
});
```

It would be really nice if someone could explain why

> $popUp.removeClass('image-add-enabled');

get ignored

Comment: are you sure its being ignored?  sure something else isnt just adding the class back after the remove fires?

Comment: whops. mybad :< popup was right inside <div> I'm was using as showPopup button. case closed

Answer (score 1):

You got error because of $popUp & $container written in wrong way
if `<div>` have `id` like that `<div id="popUp"></div>`
so that the selector of jQuery must be like that
`$('#popUp').addClass('image-add-enabled');`
but if `<div>` have `class` like that `<div class="popUp"></div>`
so that the selector of jQuery must be like that
`$('.popUp').addClass('image-add-enabled');`

You can check [jQuery reference](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details about selectors
- [Select by id reference](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [Select by class reference](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: all variables were rewritten to clean up the code before posting the question. problem is solved already.

Answer (score 0):

**Question is closed**

Popup was nested in container I'm was using as showPopup button, so basically it removed and added class on one click.